# Property [] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance using one to many relationships with laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 7.
I have two tables: `request_properties` and `requests`. `request_properties` may have many `requests` (The FK in `requests` is `request_properties_id`).
I would like to return all the id of the table `requests` starting from an `id` of the table `Request_properties` using one to many relationship in the model but I receive the following error:

```
Property [reqs] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.
```

This is the code in my controller:

```
return Request_property::where('id', 71979)->reqs->id;
```

These are the methods in my models:

Req.php

```
public function request_property()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Request_property', 'id', 'request_properties_id');
    }
```

Request_property.php

```
public function reqs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Req', 'request_properties_id', 'id');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [first()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first)

```php
Request_property::where('id', 71979)->first()->reqs()->pluck('id');
```

then use [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) get all the id of `reqs()`